# Application with reCAPTCHA Enterprise gets rejected by AppStore Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, recaptcha

I've downloaded and integrated recaptcha.framework as in Direct Download instruction https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-ios-apps#direct-download

The Debug build works just fine, no warnings or issues.

But after uploading Release build to AppStore Connect my app gets rejected with error:

> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public symbols in Giggster: __ZN3icu5Edits10addReplaceEii, __ZN3icu5Edits12addUnchangedEi. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Symbols mentioned are found only in recaptcha.framework, which ofc couldn't be deleted. So I am asking your assistance. Maybe somebody had similar experience and was successful in resollving it.

Comment: How did you resolve it, we are facing the same issue

Comment: Seeing the same thing today.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue before and I managed to pass Apple's review by degrading the reCAPTCHA enterprise SDK to 16.0.0 (17.0.0 will be rejected by Apple).